# Как записать такую логику на Js/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

как лучше сделать такой функционал. Есть `block-1`, при наведении на него `block-2` получает класс `is-active`. При удаление мышки из `block-1 block-2` удаляется класс is-active
Вопрос, как мне лучше сделать что бы была задержка.
На подобие что, если мы убираем мышку с первого блока , то через секунду удаляем класс is-active на блок 2. Но если мышка через секунду находиться на block 2 тогда не удаляем

Comment: а если через 2 секунды убрали мышку?

Answer (score 1):

Да примерно так и сделать, как написано. Задержку добавляете через `setTimeout` но при этом запоминаете время, когда его запустили. При наведении сравниваете текущее с запомненным. Если разница меньше желаемой, то таймаут убираете.

```js
var h = null;

$("#block-1").hover(function(){
      $("#block-2").addClass('is-active');      
    }, 
    function(){
       $(this).data('ts-out', (new Date()).getTime() );
       
       h = setTimeout(function(){                                
              $("#block-2").removeClass('is-active');
           }, 1000);       
    }
);
$("#block-2").mouseover(function(){
    let tsOut = $("#block-1").data('ts-out');
    let tsNow = (new Date()).getTime();

    if(tsNow - tsOut < 1000){
      clearTimeout(h);
    }
});
```

```css
.block {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

.is-active {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="block-1" class="block"></div>
<div id="block-2" class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Если убрать мышку со второго блока - он перестанет быть активным.

Comment: @OliverPatterson да, криво прочитал вопрос. было повторное наведение на блок-1, вместо перевода мыши на блок-2